# How to conditionally render or style a row of primefaces dataTable?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, row

Inside my `p:dataTable`, I am trying to render only the rows I need. Code:

```
<h:form id="f">
    <p:dataTable var="order"
        value="#{mbOrderController.ordersList}">
        <f:facet name="header">#{msg.orders}</f:facet>

        <p:column sortBy="#{order.orderNr}"
            headerText="#{msg.order_number}">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{order.orderNr}"
                rendered="#{order.type.label == 'Shoes'}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column sortBy="#{order.date}" headerText="#{msg.date}">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{order.date}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yy" />
            </p:outputLabel>
        </p:column>

        <p:column sortBy="#{order.type.label}" headerText="#{msg.type}">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{order.type.label}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

The order type label (third column) is an `Enumeration` and can be "Shoes", "Shirts" or "Pants". I only want to display rows with "Shoes".

Tried to add the `rendered` attribute to the first `p:outputLabel` which hides only this output label of course. If I add the `rendered` attribute to each `p:outputLabel` in the table, the lowest row in the table is still visible, although all cells are empty:

[image: Empty row]

How can I display only specific rows using the shown `rendered` attribute? Can anyone help?

Comment: If you want to display only Shoes, why dont you prepare the source list on the backend according to this? OR: If you want to be able to filter on the client side, why dont you use a filter on the datatable (filterBy=...) ?

Answer (score 17):

In your attempt, you're indeed only conditionally rendering the `<td>` contents, not the `<tr>`. Conditionally rendering a `<tr>` of a `<p:dataTable>` is unfortunately not possible.

You have basically two options:

1. Fix the model so that it's exactly what the view expects.

   ```
   <p:dataTable value="#{mbOrderController.shoesOrdersList}" var="shoesOrder">
   ```
2. Use `rowStyleClass` to hide or style specific rows by CSS.

   Hiding:

   ```
   <p:dataTable ... rowStyleClass="#{order.type.label == 'Shoes' ? 'ui-helper-hidden' : ''}">
   ```

   Styling:

   ```
   <p:dataTable ... rowStyleClass="#{order.type.label == 'Shoes' ? 'shoeStyle' : ''}">
   ```

   and defining a class selector containing 'shoeStyle' in css (taking [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) into account)

Answer (score -1):

try rendering  `render="#{order.type.label eq 'Shoes'}"` in column and if you don't want to write for all then you can use

```
<p:row render="#{order.type.label eq 'Shoes'}">
<p:column>
.
.
</p:row>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't chnage. If I add `rendered="#{order.type.label eq 'Shoes'}` to every `p:outputLabel` I can still see the empty row. Updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: Please add in column not in outputLabel even i mentioned in my answer, but i doubt try other option adding render in  `<p:row>` , alternatively @BalusC is saying it won't work so you can try that option as well.